# Adding a chips component in Angular 4 with Typescript

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to add a chips component to my Angular web application. It's written in Typescript, HTML, and CSS files.

I've been struggling for a few weeks trying to get it right and haven't come across the right solution.

Here is a Plunkr with my current code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/zvEP9BOktwk6nBojsZQT?p=catalogue

UPDATE: I have edited my code to reflect that I am reading an input which is a string array, called selected. I am outputting a string array called code.

Below is the code that I am working with:

```
import {
  Component, Input, HostBinding, ElementRef, ViewChild, HostListener, EventEmitter, Output, OnInit, SimpleChanges,
  OnChanges, QueryList, TemplateRef, ContentChildren, Directive
} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor} from '@angular/forms';
import {Subject} from "@reactivex/rxjs/dist/es6/Subject";

@Component({
  selector: 'chips',
  templateUrl: './chips.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chips.component.scss']

})

export class ChipsComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit{

  @Output() code: string[];
  @Input() type = 'text';
  @Input() duplicates = false;

  @Input() selected: any[];

  chips: ['chip1', 'chip2', 'chip3']

  chipItemList: any[];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("selected in chips component ngOnInit(): " + this.selected);
    console.log("code in chips component ngOnInit: " + this.code);
  }

  addChip($event){
    this.selected.push($event.target.value)
    $event.target.value = '';
  }



  /*addChip(addSelectedCode) {
    //this.newChips.next(this.addCode);
    console.log("addCode in chips component addChip(): " + this.addSelectedCode);
    if (!this.chip || !this.duplicates && this.selected.indexOf(this.chip) !== -1) return;
    this.selected.push(this.chip);
    this.chip = null;
    this.propagateChange(this.selected);
    this.selectedCodeOutput = this.addSelectedCode;
    console.log("selectedCodeOutput in chips component: " + this.selectedCodeOutput);
  } */

  remove(index: number) {
   //this.addSelectedCode.splice(index, 1);
    this.propagateChange(this.selected);
    this.selectedCodeOutput = this.addSelectedCode;
  }

  /*
   Form Control Value Accessor
   */
  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value !== undefined) this.selected = value;
  }

  propagateChange = (_: any) => {
  };

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() {
  }


}
```

I believe the issue is that I'm not able to call my child component from my parent template.

Does anyone have any helpful advice for getting the chips component to add chips?

Thank you!

Comment: if selectedCodeOutput is your @Output(), how come are you trying to log it into ngOnInit() function? What sorta value do you see there? Usually when one creates an Output to talk back with the parent component, they usually set them as angular's event emitter and emitting certain type.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm trying to log it to see what it contains. It's actually not even getting to ngOnInit in my chips component. I tried using an EventEmitter but it didn't produce the desired result.

Comment: have you added your chipsComponent to the declarations array of app module? When you use @Output(), it basically means that the child is alerting the parent on any changes. In service-alert component, you are calling the child using its selector 'chips'. A mistake there is that you are listening to (addSelectedCode) but you are not directing it to any specific purpose. You'd want to do some work, preferably with a function, when there is an output from the child. sth like this (addSelectedCode)="onSelectedCodeAddition($event)". Also, have you declared service-alert component in app module?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do ?You are not explaining the problem clearly.Your plunker doesnt have any useful code,it just shows hello message.Cant interpret your problem properly.Please elaborate your question.

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya I'm trying to add a chip to my web application. I'm sorry, it's the first time I'm working with Plunker.

This is a link to a chip demo, similar to what I am trying to do:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips

Hope that helps. Let me know if  you have specific questions on what I'm doing...

Comment: @AnjilDhamala   I've declared both chipsComponent and ServiceAlertsComponent in my app.module.ts. 

I tried using the method you suggested ($event)...either I am not doing it properly or it's not the functionality I am looking for.

Comment: Either the plunker is incomplete or it is buggy because the service component's html is missing a closing div tag and I don't see your component declarations in app module. anyways, I don't see a route setup to get to service component or a service component selector in app's template. If you are just starting to fiddle with angular then I'd suggest to start with starter tutorial at angular.io (https://angular.io/tutorial)

Comment: @AnjilDhamala I added the closing div tag. I had copied and pasted from my code in intelliJ and missed to copy the closing tag.I will check on the component declarations in app module. I have gone through the Tour of Heroes tutorial on angular.io. It helped a bit. I don't have a service component, I think I can just do it with Inputs and Outputs...that's what my colleague said.

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up your plunker and now I can get all the way to `ngOnInit()` in chips component without any error. Take it from here and let us know if you need help in setting up the logic. But before all that, I would like to ask you to refer to the docs on `@Input()` and `@Ouput()` decorators.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sdfbWpe0u5SCHj5xBqtX?p=preview)

Comment: I will refer to the docs on @Input() and @Output() decorators one more time. Thank you for your help! Will also work on setting up the logic correctly.

Comment: I worked on setting up the logic. I also looked into @Input() and @Output() decorators. I found that I needed to use @ViewChild in order to access the child method from the parent template. 

I am working on coding the chips component currently. Thank you once more for your help.

Comment: Actually, you use @ViewChild to select a template tag from the parent component. But if you are talking about communication between parent and child component then Input and Output is the way to go. :)

Comment: I've finished coding chips component! Thank you all for your help!